# ElasticSearch query to retrieve results only when all fields match my filter?

Tags: c#, mysql, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

I need to do an ElasticSearch query where I have an array of objects, and filter for the condition where all of the items in that array match.  Here is my mapping:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "myindexType":{
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "_all":{
        "enabled": false
      },      
      "properties":{
      "thisthing": {
          "properties": {
            "thingTypeId": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "thingId": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "description": { 
          "type": "keyword"

        },
        "text": { 
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my indexed data:

```
POST myindex/myindexType
{
  "thisthing": [
            {
              "thingId": "1",
              "thingTypeId": "42"
            },
            {
              "thingId": "1",
              "thingTypeId": "43"
            },
            {
              "thingId": "1",
              "thingTypeId": "44"
            }

          ],
    "description":"something",
    "text":"something"


}
```

And here is the query I have so far:

```
GET _search
{"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [ {
            "match": {
                "text": {
                    "query": "something",
                    "fuzziness": "Auto",
                    "operator": "and"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "filter": [
          {"term": {"thisthing.thingTypeId": "42" } },
          {"term": {"thisthing.thingTypeId": "43" } }

      ]
}}}
```

My query brings back results, because the ids 42, and 43 both exist in the indexed data.  However, I want a query where it would NOT bring back results unless all of the ids in the indexed data exist in my filter.  Tried this with both term and terms filter without luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested objects in array to solve you problem. [Here](http://obtao.com/blog/2014/04/elasticsearch-advanced-search-and-nested-objects/) you can find good description of your case.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't know how that article resolves the issue.  Let's say I have a query with ids 1,2,3.  The index has data 1,2,3,4.  The query should not return results because the data has an id not in the query.  Every example I have seen so far would return results because the query contains ids that are in the data.  I actually want the opposite.  Thanks,,,